# System.MissingMethodException - only on device startup

Tags: c#, compact-framework, windows-ce

Our C# 2.0 CF (CompactFramework) application targets older devices running Windows CE 5.0 and 6.0. The project builds a number of DLLs to provide functionality such as RS-232 comms.

On the Windows CE 5.0 device, a `MissingMethodException` is thrown, referencing one of these DLLs. This happens early in the application startup process and only immediately after a power cycle. If we kill the application and restart, the exception is not thrown and the application works perfectly. Same result if we deploy using Visual Studio for debugging (no exception).

No exception is thrown on the Windows CE 6.0 devices.

Since this occurs only immediately after a power cycle and we cannot debug the project, what can I try to track down where and what is causing the problem?

#### Update

The answer from `josef` is useful. Use `IsAPIReady` on CE 5.0 with one of these sub-systems:

```
const uint SH_GDI_CE5               = 16;   // Most useful
const uint SH_WMGR_CE5              = 17;   // Most useful
const uint SH_SHELL_CE5             = 21;   // Most useful
const uint SH_WNET_CE5              = 18;
const uint SH_COMM_CE5              = 19;
const uint SH_FILESYS_APIS_CE5      = 20;
const uint SH_DEVMGR_APIS_CE5       = 22;
const uint SH_TAPI_CE5              = 23;
const uint SH_PATCHER_CE5           = 24;
const uint SH_SERVICES_CE5          = 26;
```

Or use `WaitForAPIReady` on CE 6.0 with one of these sub-systems:

```
const uint SH_GDI_CE6               = 80;   // Most useful
const uint SH_WMGR_CE6              = 81;   // Most useful
const uint SH_SHELL_CE6             = 85;   // Most useful
const uint SH_WNET_CE6              = 82;
const uint SH_COMM_CE6              = 83;
const uint SH_FILESYS_APIS_CE6      = 84;
const uint SH_DEVMGR_APIS_CE6       = 86;
const uint SH_TAPI_CE6              = 87;
const uint SH_DDRAW_CE6             = 91;
const uint SH_D3DM_CE6              = 92;
```

But, embarrassingly, the actual problem turned out not to be a low-level OS/CLR problem but that the application had been accidentally started twice on power-up. The 1st time was using the `HKLM\init` registry key, but some (unknown) user had added a shortcut to the `Startup` folder. These two instances started up so quickly one after each other I did not notice at first. It was the 2nd instance that crashed.

The solution was to check on startup for multiple instances of the application using `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`. If a 2nd instance is detected, the application aborts.

Will leave this question active for anyone who follows...

Comment: It is more like an OS/CLR level issue (the exception can be caused by CLR bugs instead of your code). Report to Microsoft support team and only with their assistance you might be able to learn the culprit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a device starts, not all APIs are ready to use from the beginning as those are loaded asynchronously. Therefor WinCE offers the isApiReady function: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/embedded/ms885686%28v%3dmsdn.10%29

On startup of device it loads drivers, services and finally the shell according to the order of the init registry key. Your code probably uses an API that is not yet loaded and so fails.

An example of isApiReady use can be found at https://github.com/hjgode/RAC_switch/blob/master/RAC_switch/WinAPIReady.cs

Comment: Thanks. I actually do that in another context...will see about implementing this when next in the office and report back.

Comment: Well, this is embarrassing! The actual problem occurs when TWO instances of my application are running! The application is already started on power cycle from the HKLM\init registry key. However, a shortcut to the application had been added by some (unknown) user to the `Startup` folder. It was this 2nd application instance that crashes, but so fast after the 1st grabs low-level RS-232 comms that I did not notice at first.

Issue resolved by checking for any other instances on startup and aborting if required. Will update the question with this information.